# Functions that satisfy $f(x,z) = f(x,y) f(y,z)$

Tags: analysis, functions

I am specifically looking for solutions that are **NOT** of the form: $f(x,y) = g(x)/g(y)$ since that is an obvious solution, as is $f(x,y) = 0$. I have a suspicion that there may be answers to this question that do not fall into these categories.

The functions don't necessarily have to be continuous or differentiable.

Edit: $f$ is not necessarily defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$, it can be defined on any space you like. Basically the equation deals with functions of two variables/arguments.

Edit #2: Domains are irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Some domains and codomains are in need, otherwise it's impossible to answer. And the definition of $f\cdot f$ too.

Comment: Wouldn't the domains and codomains depend on the specific function? I don't want to restrict them in general, because I don't know what restrictions will lead to more interesting answers. Why is a definition of $f \cdot f$ needed?

Comment: You seem to be taking $f$ defined in some subset of $\Bbb R^2$. but you didn't mention it at all. Why not consider $f$ defined on $\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 0 & e\end{bmatrix}, \pi, \zeta\text{ function}\right\}^2$?

Comment: $x,y,z$ don't have to be real numbers. They could be anything if that helps form a different solution. So, your reformulation works.

Comment: And that's why I say it is impossible to answer. In the set above, I can define $f\cdot f$ anyway I see fit just as long as it meets the criteria.

Comment: Are the any specific common formulations of $f \cdot f$ that lead to interesting answers? I am not looking for a completely generalized answer.

Comment: @GitGud: Are domains relevant to this problem? It seems only the codomains matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, either the function is zero everywhere or nowhere.  If $f(a,b)=0$, then $f(a,b')=0f(b,b')=0$, and then $f(a',b')=f(a',a)f(a,b')=0$.  Since this is for any $(a',b')$, the function is everywhere zero.

Second, suppose the function is zero nowhere.  Now we have $\frac{f(x,z)}{f(x,y)}=f(y,z)$, is independent of $x$.  Define $g(t)=f(1,t)$.  We have $\frac{g(z)}{g(y)}=f(y,z)$.  Hence the other "obvious" solution you mention is the only other possibility.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $f(a,b')=0f(b,b')=0$ for the first step in showing if zero once then for all $a,b$? (Likely a typo.)

Comment: @coffeemath, thanks for the sharp eyes.

Comment: As @Git suggested, the functions don't have to be defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$. So, do you think there can be other solutions if you relax that restriction?